# Не испускается сигнал

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

У меня есть три формы. По нажатию кнопки на первой форме появляется вторая. По нажатию кнопки на второй форме появляется третья. По нажатию кнопки на третьей форме передаётся информация на первую форму.

Возникает проблема с передачей сигнала первой форме. Проблема заключается в следующем.

Связываю сигнал из третьей формы и слот из первой.

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(send_signal_replot_R(DAG) ), this->baseClass, SLOT(replot_matrix_R(DAG) ) );
```

Сигнал объявлен так:

```
signals:
    void send_signal_replot_R(DAG graph);
```

Слот объявлен так:

```
public slots:
    void replot_matrix_R(DAG graph);
```

Слот представляет собой такую фунцию:

```
void Main_Window::replot_matrix_R(DAG graph)
{
    this->graph = graph;

    ui->widget->Graph() = graph;
    ui->widget->before_paint();
    ui->widget->repaint();
    return;
}
```

Вызываю сигнал так:

```
emit this->send_signal_replot_R(graph);
```

В итоге получаю нечто такое:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect Calculate::send_signal_replot_R(DAG) to (null)::Main_Window::replot_matrix_R(DAG)
```

Мне непонятно, что такое (null). Это немного странно, т.е. не слот не связан с классом что ли? Или в чём бага? Пробовал модифицировать связь со слотом на такую, но не помогло:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(send_signal_replot_R(DAG) ), this->baseClass, SLOT(Main_Window::replot_matrix_R(DAG) ) );
```

Инициализация `this->baseClass`:

```
Calculate::Calculate(int countMatrix, int countVertex, QWidget *baseClass, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Calculate)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->countVertex = countVertex;
    this->countMatrix = countMatrix;

    this->SetNameLabel(1, countMatrix);
    InitMatrix();



    this->matrixGraph.resize(countVertex, countVertex, 0);

    this->baseClass = baseClass;

    this->currentCountMatrix = 0;

    return;
}
```

connect расположен внутри метода:

```
void Calculate::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
        ...
        connect(this, SIGNAL(send_signal_replot_R(DAG) ), this->baseClass, SLOT(Main_Window::replot_matrix_R(DAG) ) );

        ...

        emit this->send_signal_replot_R(graph);
        ...
}
```

Comment: Вы где-нибудь некий Calculate используете?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Calculate -- в нём объявлен сигнал send_signal_replot_R(DAG)

Comment: А моки пересобирали после модификации, так, на всякий случай?..

Comment: У `baseClass` ведь есть слот `replot_matrix_R`?

Comment: @gil9red baseClass -- это Main_Window

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов да, пересобирал. Сейчас, конечно, ещё раз попробую. Но не лечилось этим.

Comment: покажите где проитсходит инициализация this->baseClass

Comment: @Embedder, поправил вопрос, смотрите выше.

Comment: @hedgehogues А где в конструкторе connect?

Comment: @Embedder connect расположен внутри метода. См. выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связывание лучше сделать в конструкторе, а не на обработчике нажатия кнопки.

```
this->baseClass = baseClass;
connect(this, SIGNAL(send_signal_replot_R(DAG) ), this->baseClass, SLOT(replot_matrix_R(DAG) ) );
```

Проверьте как у вас создается экземпляр класса **Calculate**, а конкретно что передается в качестве значения параметра **QWidget *baseClass**. Дело в том что connect производит "позднее" связывание, т.е. на этапе выполнения. Если **baseClass == null**, то вы получаете ошибку. Других причин для ошибки из представленного кода, я не вижу.

Comment: Да, заработало. Спасибо Вам. Не передавал указатель. А он по умолчанию присваивался 0.